# .NET exceptions I can throw for Not Authorized or Not Authenticated

Tags: c#, exception, authentication, authorization

I have parts of code where I want to throw an Exception whenever a user is not authenticated/not authorized.

So instead of writing my own NotAuthenticatedException and NotAuthorizedException, I was wondering if there are not already some C# standards for these.

I can imagine a lot of programs throw similar Exceptions, and it would not be very useful if everyone 'writes their own wheel' again.

Comment: You may use `SecurityException` for both scenarios.

Comment: What is the problem with throw new NotAuthorizedException? If you think it is not encapsulated enough, just encapsulate it in a static class.

Comment: @Fendy Pretty sure he means writing his *own* NotAuthorizedException, not the actual code `throw new NotAuthorizedException();`...

Comment: In asp.net I'm using HttpException(401, "Unauthorized") resp. my own
HttpUnauthorizedExeption() : base((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized"){ } for better readability

Comment: @Liero why raise Http Exceptions when this could be data level authorisation? E.g. Dirk might be wanting to raise a NotAuthorisedException because the user does not have access to a particular customer's records?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the C# [AuthenticationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.authenticationexception) or [InvalidCredentialException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.invalidcredentialexception) class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.authenticationexception

Comment: I don't think these exceptions are appropriate for failed authorization, or for an unauthenticated (anonymous) user.  They're intended for the situation where a client presents credentials that are invalid, which is different from not presenting any credentials at all.

Comment: I think AuthenticationException is perfectly valid. Directly from MSDN: The classes throw this exception when the client or server cannot be authenticated, which IMO is what the OP is asking for.  I believe there may be a better class for Authrorization, as you and others have mentioend `SecurityException`.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation.  MSDN says these exceptions are used "when authentication fails for an authentication stream", i.e. during the process of authenticating the client.  My reading of the OP's situation is that the authentication process has already completed, and he needs to decide whether to authorize an anonymous or an authenticated user.

Comment: Authentication is not authorization. One could be authenticated as a "banned user" for instance but would not be authorized to use the site.

Comment: @ssg - I understand the difference between the two. If you feel you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: @DarrenDavies The word "or" in your answer says otherwise.

Comment: @ssg - Would you like to clarify?

Comment: @DarrenDavies I'm sorry I thought InvalidCredentialsException was for authorization, not authentication. That's why I wanted to point out two notions are different. OP might still be thinking that though. The way he wrote the question implies it.

Comment: I would understand `AuthenticationException` to indicate something went wrong in the process of authentication, so I would expect this to be thrown in some sort of login method.  Doesn't seem it is as fitted to the situation of the user not being logged in, which could include no such authentication process even happening.

Answer (score 66):

You could also use [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx)  for authorization violations

Comment: The name sounds good, but the documentation says "An UnauthorizedAccessException exception is typically thrown by a method that wraps a Windows API call."  For the scenario presented in this question, this could potentially be misleading.  Better to throw a custom exception than reuse a framework exception intended for a completely different context.

Comment: I think the key word in that MS remark is 'typically' which suggests that the text to follow is an example. If I were to look at some code that caught an UnauthorizedAccessViolation I would think that an unauthorized access attempt had been made and not necessarily one by 'a method that wraps a Windows API call'.

Comment: So now I'm admittedly splitting hairs, but the PrivilegeNotHeldException inherits from UnauthorizedAccessException, which means any try/catch block handling the UnauthorizedAccessException would try to handle that exception, which is not what you would intend to happen.  This is rhetorical and a bit of a stretch, but if you were writing a chat program, and detected a spat ensuing between two participants, would you throw an ArgumentException?  Aren't you trying to imply semantics around the exception that wouldn't match those the original exception was intended for, or used by others?

Comment: It should be noted that the reason the Windows API call throws this exception is usually because the user doesn't have permission to access a file/folder. So it still fits the overall theme of a generic not authorized exception.

Comment: I agree with @G-Mac UnauthorizedAccessException doesn't seem to be right for this scenario

Answer (score 10):

To avoid reinventing the wheel, I'd use [PrincipalPermission.Demand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.demand.aspx) or [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx).

A `SecurityException` will be thrown for you if the demand fails.

If you do want to explicitly throw an exception rather than using `PrincipalPermission.Demand`, you could consider reusing the existing type [System.UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx), which is described in MSDN as:

> The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

It's your app rather than the OS that's denying access, but perhaps close enough.

Comment: IIRC, we're not supposed to throw SystemException derivatives ourselves. They are not intended for general use.

Comment: @ssg, I don't agree with that. The MSDN Exception handling guidelines (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) state "In most cases, use the predefined exceptions types".

Comment: I see your MSDN and raise my own: "Do not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx

Comment: @ssg - ... and therefore by implication, you may throw other built-in exception types from your own code.

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException derives from SystemException. I wish the document had given a clear reason for why "SystemException" was forbidden and whether it applied to its derivatives.

Comment: @ssg - Well, it also forbids System.Exception, and clearly this can not apply to its derivatives.

Comment: I realize this is a very old question, but still relevant and still confusing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions clearly indicates that throwing System.Exception derivatives is ok and preferred as @Joe indicates (specifically ArgumentException and InvalidOperationException)